# New bounty system == The mega upvote?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have yet to place a bounty [using the new system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) yet, but I already see a possible unintended consequence. You can now do a mega-upvote on any answer using a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

```
reputation !== votes
```

Thinking it over, it *does* allow for transferring reputation from sockpuppet accounts. But I guess using multiple sockpuppets to give each other enough reputation will be taken care of by [Vote Fraud and You](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) and the like, before that reputation can even be transferred by (ab)using a bounty.

Comment: `syntax error at line 1. unexpected token '=' at end of operator`

Comment: And also I'm not saying it is, but I'm saying you can give a huge upvote to someone worth however much rep you want, and you can do it any amount of times.

Comment: @earlz - mega upvote in the reputation meaning, yes, but not as an actual "vote". It won't make the answer more visible, or on top

Comment: @earlz, try a language that supports [the identity operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparison-operators-differ) ;-)

Comment: @Gnou but adding a bounty does bump the question to the front page

Comment: @Earlz: He could be (for some gosh darn unknown reason) writing his pseudocode in PHP, where !== is a totally valid, and silly, operator!

Comment: @Phoshi, I'd say it's more like PHP's `==` behaves silly and hence needs the `===` to make up for that. Likewise in JavaScript, `"1" == 1` but without type coercion `"2" !== 2`. Perl uses `===` to ensure two variables are actually the very same object instance (just like Java's `==`). Not always too silly if you'd ask me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open another question claiming that bounty now allows too much rep transfer, fine, but as stated this is noise or pointless:

- has nothing to do with actual votes
- you haven't even thought through any potential problems based on usage or even walked us through a possible scenario

Comment: if you're ok with it just delete this post then(I can't due to 2 day reopen thing)

Comment: @Jeff, not like I care about it (hence deleting this question is fine), but do you think sockpuppets would go unnoticed? A few could vote up one another, and then eventually grant a bounty to some other account to transfer the reputation. But I guess this is already covered by [Vote Fraud and You](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) and the like.

Comment: @Arjan I just covered this in a new question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54306/question-bump-possibility-with-new-bounty-system

Comment: @Earlz, [that other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54306/question-bump-possibility-with-new-bounty-system) is about bumping, not about earning reputation by using sockpuppets, right?

Comment: What new bounty system? Did I miss something? (Edit: aaaah, I see. Wow, this is magnificent!)

Comment: @Arj bumping leads to earning reputation though, so sorta.