# Question bump possibility with new bounty system

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, gaming-the-system

With [the new bounty system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) anyone can attach a bounty to a question. When a bounty is placed, a question is also bumped.

Take UserA and UserB both with over 200 reputation. They are either owned by the same person or are friends. UserA and UserB post an answer on each others questions. Well, the question asked by both of them got a few upvotes but they feel they should've have gotten more attention. So UserA attaches a bounty to his own question as does UserB. At the end of the 7 days they award the bounty to each other, hence no reputation is lost between them and they both get on the featured tab and on the front page for a while. They can then repeat this multiple times.

In order to combat this, I propose a new feature-request that bounties count as an edit entry. This way after more than a couple times of doing this the question will become community wiki as well as the answers.

Comment: much better, this is at least a reasonable Q

Comment: @Jeff It's 4:13am here, give me some slack :)

Answer (score 7):

This could actually happen every 24 hours, once the question is more than 2 days old (the minimum to attach a bounty).

The consequences, though, are pretty minor:

- the question would get bumped to the homepage every 24 hours
- the question would stay on the featured tab of the homepage forever (though it'd be near the oldest/bottom every single time, so probably not visible to most)
- one answer would get a very large accumulated bounty rep score, but the net rep change is zero for each account

None of that seems very "bad" to me.

Eventually, I think this question would get flagged for mod attention, we'd see the accumulated bounty score and bounty history, and we'd delete the question and suspend one or both users.

Comment: but what if the question bumped is not by the bumpers but by someone else and they just decided to exploit the system for bumping? deletion would in that case be rather unfair, but what about eliminating the total bounty from each of the bumpers' rep?